How to fix CS8347 when defining a ref struct?
struct Locker
{
    private SpinLock _lock;

    public Lock Acquire() => new(ref _lock);
}
ref struct Lock
{
    private ref SpinLock _lock;
    private bool _lockTaken;
        
    public Lock(ref SpinLock @lock)
    {
        _lock = ref @lock;
        _lock.Enter(ref _lockTaken);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (!_lockTaken) return;

        _lockTaken = false;
        _lock.Exit();
    }
}

I'm getting a CS8347 error on the line defining the Acquire method. How do I get rid of it preserving the core functionality?

I need the Locker structure to contain only SpinLock value
I need the Lock structure to contain a reference to Lock structure, or to their values + _lockTaken field


You don't, basically; if that was possible, it could lead to very nasty outcomes including stack corruption; imagine some method: static Lock Evil() => new Locker().Acquire(); - now call using(Evil()) {...} - where is that pointing? (hint: into the middle of a stack-frame that no longer exists)

@MarcGravell Lock is a ref struct, why it's allowed to move it out?

Because there's nothing illegal about returning a ref struct; the inputs to a ref struct are guarded by CS8347 et al

What is the core functionality? Is Locker._lock necessary?

@shingo no, Marc's answer worked. I just wanted to abstract from the concrete lock type, but I guess it doesn't matter that much. At least, the code compiles now

Of course we all know all these CS error numbers by heart.

Maybe this - move the ownership out one layer:
SpinLock obj = default;
using (obj.Acquire())
{
    // ...
}
static class SpinLockExtensions
{
    public static Lock Acquire(ref this SpinLock @lock)
        => new(ref @lock);
}

